# Cleaning up a crime scene and its evidence

Tags: plot, planning, mystery, crime, thriller

If a crime scene is cleaned up well, what possible evidence would still be found if they managed somehow to clean up the blood, discard the murder weapon, and hide the body?

Is it possible for a criminal to clean up all the evidence/crime scene 100%? I doubt that is possible since I expect that they slip up and didn't clean up evidence that the police could find. That's I what would expect, though it might be possible but difficult.

Comment: What is the goal of cleaning up the crime scene, here? So the police can't find the crime scene, or so that they can't find evidence to track down/convict the culprit? Because in the latter case, contaminating the crime scene with tons of distracting evidence might be easier.

Comment: Its a murder. Blood, weapons, they can get those as evidence to get the suspect.

Comment: If you rob a blood bank before committing the murder, and then pour all the stolen blood over the murder scene, they'll have one hell of a time finding any blood from the murder. More so if you cleaned *that* up a bit beforehand. It would be rather noticeable though. Which is why I'm asking what the goal is. If you don't care that they know the murder scene, you can (try to) make it unusable in many different ways (setting it on fire is often popular). But if you want to make it difficult for them to find the murder scene in the first place, then you need to be a lot more subtle.

Comment: @towr - "If you rob a blood bank" - that's definitely not that easy. There is little point of doing it if the crime scene is immediately secured by authorities (only if perpetrator's own blood is spilled), and it would be quite a dumb thing to do if crime took place at perpetrator's place ("You say he was killed in my house? Ha! There's blood all over the place, you see. Good luck linking that to your victim's").

Comment: @Alexander I hope you didn't really expect me to give people good advice on how to get away with murder, here ;) And really, the things you mention are the whole point. We _don't know_ if the crime scene is immediately secured by authorities, nor if the scene is the perpetrators house. No cover-up plans will be generally applicable. The only good advice for a would-be murderer is "don't do it". Saves a ton of trouble.

Comment: @towr My point is that cover up is elaborate and requires more effort, while clean up is usually straightforward.

Comment: @Alexander Cleaning is also cover-up. And it's only straightforward if you just need to do it well enough so that things don't look suspicious at first glance. If you want to do it well enough to stand up to forensic investigation, then you have to get elaborate again. Because if you're not careful, then all the while you're scrubbing the murder scene, you're just shedding more DNA all over the place.

Comment: @towr - for clean up, one needs to be thorough and careful. For cover up, one not only needs to be thorough and careful (on the same level), but also resourceful and creative. Of course, I admit, cover up makes a much more interesting story :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fingerprints, footprints, possibly hair from the victim, on the murderer or in his car.

Even video. Police have captured criminals because victims had hidden cameras recording, both inside and outside their houses. Some offices and businesses secretly record both outside and inside, e.g. every entry into their building. It is a matter of routine security. A business I worked at several years ago was burglarized at night and computers were stolen. The company had video inside the halls of the two guys, no masks, carrying stuff out. (If there had been a murder I think they would have looked for them harder.)

If you are just looking for a plot device, make your victim a paranoid guy with disguised video cameras that look like bird houses or garden gnomes, recording to the Cloud; so even if the house is burned down, those videos still exist. Maybe his brother or sister knows how to find them.